# How to rearrange rows to different columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table to log products which employee made at spcified date, here is its structure:

```
EmpId   Date        ProductA ProductB
001     01/01/2018  5        3
001     01/02/2018  2        5
002     01/01/2018  3        4
002     01/02/2018  1        2
```

Here is sample report which I must achieve from above table:

```
           01/01/2018           01/02/2018
EmpId  ProductA  ProductB  ProductA  ProductB
001    5         3         2         5
002    3         4         1         2
```

... Maybe it is difficult to have perfect solution, you can show me a link, clip or related document to resolve issue, appreciate your help, thanks!

Comment: show us what you have already tried?

Comment: Sorry about table layout, I wrote thread from mobile, at office, I tried with pivot however it only push 1 column ProductA when assign pivot for date, something as: EmpId | ProductA, I got stuck with ProductB ...

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: I can't see Edit button more, seem SOF only permit editing in specified time..., I was using SQL Server 2014, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pivot query.. but clumsy if have too many date values..

```
with t(empid, date, ProductA, ProductB) as
(
select '001', '01/01/2018',  5, 3 union all
select '001', '01/02/2018',  2, 5 union all
select '002', '01/01/2018',  3, 4 union all
select '002', '01/02/2018',  1, 2 
)
select empid,
sum(case when date='01/01/2018' then ProductA end) ProductA,
sum(case when date='01/01/2018' then ProductB end) ProductB,
sum(case when date='01/02/2018' then ProductA end) ProductA,
sum(case when date='01/02/2018' then ProductB end) ProductB 
from t
group by empid
```

Comment: Unfortunately, report must permit user choose any month to extract data (30-31 columns date...) my company software support feature sql dynamic, I will check it later.